# Python3 adding an extra byte to the byte string

Tags: python-3.x

```
file_1 = (r'res\test.png')

with open(file_1, 'rb') as file_1_:
file_1_read = file_1_.read()    
file_1_hex = binascii.hexlify(file_1_read)
print ('Hexlifying test.png..')

pack = ("test.packet") 

file_1_size_bytes = len(file_1_read)

print (("test.png is"),(file_1_size_bytes),("bytes."))

struct.pack( 'i', file_1_size_bytes)
file_1_size_bytes_hex = binascii.hexlify(struct.pack( '>i', file_1_size_bytes))
print (("Hexlifyed length - ("),(file_1_size_bytes_hex),(")."))

with open(pack, 'ab') as header_1_:
header_1_.write(binascii.unhexlify(file_1_size_bytes_hex))

print (("("),(binascii.unhexlify(file_1_size_bytes_hex)),(")"))

with open(pack, 'ab') as header_head_1:
header_head_1.write(binascii.unhexlify("0000020000000D007200650073002F00000074006500730074002E0070006E006700000000"))
print ("Header part 1 added.")
```

So this writes "0000020000000D007200650073002F00000074006500730074002E0070006E006700000000(00)" to the pack unhexlifyed.

There's an extra "00" byte at the end. this is messing everything up im trying to do because the packets length is referred back to when loading it and i have about 13 extra "00" bytes at the end of each string i write to the file. So in turn my file is 13 bytes longer than it should be. Not to mention the headers byte length isnt being read properly because the padding is off by 1 byte.

Comment: i guess ill just delete the extra byte from the end of the line.. i really dont want to do that tho: / i need the entirety of the header..

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be saying that binascii.unhexlify does not really condense the input string.  I have trouble believing that. Here is a minimal complete runnable example and the output I get with 3.4.2 on Win 7.

```
import binascii
import io

b = binascii.unhexlify(
    "000000030000000100000000000000040041004E0049004D00000000000000")
print(b)  # bytes
bf = io.BytesIO()
bf.write(b)
print(bf.getvalue())

>>> 
b'\x00\x00\x00\x03\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x04\x00A\x00N\x00I\x00M\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
b'\x00\x00\x00\x03\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x04\x00A\x00N\x00I\x00M\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
```

Unhexlify has converted each pair of hex characters to the byte expected.

Comment: No im saying is im writing the string, then a header peice then another string, and when i match it to what it should be theres an extra 00 byte on it. i didnt say im positive that my code is correct. i came here for help with this error. whether its mine or pythons.

Comment: Are you mixing unicode strings and bytes?  Write and post a minimal complete verifiable example (see stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows such a problem, and write to BytesIO as I did, not a disk file.

Comment: BytesIO is slow, and not what im trying to do. im writting to a file for a reason. ill update the example more to suffice you.